# How to copy a System.Drawing.Graphics over another Graphics?

Tags: .net

We got some code that implement printing using `Printdocument` and it does all the drawing directly on the `Graphics` object received in the `PrintEventArgs`. It would be more convenient if the code doing the drawing used another canvas and we would add this canvas to the `PrintEventArgs` `Graphics` after. Since the code already depends on the `Graphics` object I need a canvas with this object. I also need a way to copy the canvas onto the `PrintEventArgs` `Graphics`. I can create a `Graphics`from an `Image` but as far as I know it needs to be stored on the disk. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty bitmap, get the bitmap's graphics object, and do your painting on that. You can save the bitmap to disk or wherever if you need to retrieve it later. Then paint the bitmap on top of your graphics object whenever you need that layer to be added. Should be pretty straightforward.